# Using Knockout JS and Twitter Bootstrap.. pre-pend icon looks good in IE but bad in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: cross-browser, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working with Knockout JS and recently have added Twitter Bootstrap to the UI and it's been great.

However I recently found that my awesome form looks good in IE, but looks like a mess in Chrome/Firefox.

JSFiddle...... run in IE and then Chrome/FF

http://jsfiddle.net/smatthews1999/9SwJR/5/

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
<button><i class="icon-star"></i></button>
```

Instead of:

```
<button><i class="icon-star"/></button>
```